# Trouble with JSON Array Form

Tags: json

I can't figure out why this is not valid JSON after testing it with jsonlint.com.  It's just an array of objects and I don't see anything missing or out of place.

```
[
    {
        “rel”: “self”,
        "href": "http://ourdomain/persons",
        "name": {
            "last": "best"
        }
    },
    {
        “rel”: “self”,
        "href": "http://ourdomain/persons",
        "name": {
            "last": "bet"
        }
    },
    {
        “rel”: “self”,
        "href": "http://ourdomain/persons",
        "name": {
            "last": "brown"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the quotation marks wrapping **rel** and **self**.

```
[
{
    "rel": "self",
    "href": "http://ourdomain/persons",
    "name": {
        "last": "best"
    }
},
{
    "rel": "self",
    "href": "http://ourdomain/persons",
    "name": {
        "last": "bet"
    }
},
{
    "rel": "self",
    "href": "http://ourdomain/persons",
    "name": {
        "last": "brown"
    }
}
```

]

DONE!

Answer (score 1):

The problem you've got is the quotes are being replaced with another HTML character.

If you look here `“rel”: “self”,` you'll noticed that it's using `“` and not `"`. Replace them and you should be fine.